# Will consteval functions allow template parameters dependent on function arguments?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++20, class-template

In C++17, this code is illegal:

```
constexpr int foo(int i) {
    return std::integral_constant<int, i>::value;
}
```

That's because even if `foo` can be evaluated at compile-time, the compiler still needs to produce the instructions to execute it at runtime, thus making the template instantiation impossible.

In C++20 we will have `consteval` functions, which are required to be evaluated at compile-time, so the runtime constraint should be removed. Does it mean this code will be legal?

```
consteval int foo(int i) {
    return std::integral_constant<int, i>::value;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, no. `i` is (yet) not considered a core constant expression at that very moment.

Comment: cppreference has *The consteval specifier declares a function or function template to be an immediate function [...] An immediate function is a constexpr function, and must satisfy the requirements applicable to constexpr functions or constexpr constructors, as the case may be.* so signs point to no.  My reading of the standard leads me to the same conclusion but I'm not certain enough to state that in an answer.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411673).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No.

Whatever changes the paper will entail, which is little [at this point](http://wg21.link/p1073), it cannot change the fact that a non-template function definition is only typed once. Moreover, if your proposed code would be legal, we could presumably find a way to declare a variable of type `std::integral_constant<int, i>`, which feels very prohibitive in terms of the ODR.

The paper also indicates that parameters are not intended to be treated as core constant expressions in one of its examples;

```
consteval int sqrsqr(int n) {
  return sqr(sqr(n)); // Not a constant-expression at this  point,
}                     // but that's okay.
```

In short, function parameters will never be constant expressions, due to possible typing discrepancy.

Comment: Note that it does allow you to pass an argument of a `consteval` function to another `consteval` function, even though the argument is not technically a constant expression.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's by permission on the side of immediate functions though, not on the side of the arguments. As you said: those aren't constant expressions, and template parameters require those for good reason.

Answer (score 40):

> Does it mean this code will be legal?
>
> ```
> consteval int foo(int i) {
>     return std::integral_constant<int, i>::value;
> }
> ```

No. This is still ill-formed. While `consteval` requires the call itself to be a constant expression, so you know that the argument that produces `i` must be a constant expression, `foo` itself is still not a template. Template?

A slight variation in your example might make this more obvious:

```
consteval auto foo(int i) {
    return std::integral_constant<int, i>();
}
```

Were this to be valid, `foo(1)` and `foo(2)` would... return different types. This is an entirely different language feature ([constexpr function parameters](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1045r0.html)) - because in order for this to work, such functions would really need to behave like templates.

It may seem a little unintuitive. After all, if the argument that produced `i` was a constant expression, surely `i` should be usable as one as well? But it's still not - there are no additional exceptions in [expr.const] that permit parameters for immediate functions. An immediate function is still just a function, and its parameters still aren't constant expressions -- in the same way that a normal `constexpr` function's parameters aren't constant expressions.

---

Of course with `int`, we can just rewrite the function to lift the function parameter into a template parameter:

```
template <int i>
consteval int foo() {
    return std::integral_constant<int, i>::value;
}
```

And C++20 gives us class types as non-type template parameters, so we can actually do this for many more types than we could before. But there are still plenty of types that we could use as a parameter to an immediate function that we cannot use as a template parameter - so this won't always work (e.g. `std::optional` or, more excitingly in C++20, `std::string`).

Comment: Can't we use a helper like `consteval int to_constexpr(int x) { return x; }`, and then `return std::integral_constant<int, to_constexpr(i)>::value;` from (the non-templated version of) `foo()`? If yes, then current non-`constexpr`'ness of parameters looks like a useless restriction.

Comment: @Ruslan No. Because `to_constexpr(x)` is not a constant expression, which is allowed as it's inside a `consteval` function definition.

Answer (score 11):

It would seem that this will not be legal in C++20. A good explanation for why this would be problematic to support has already been given in the answers by @Barry and @Columbo (it doesn't really work with the type system). I'll just add what I believe to be the relevant quotes from the standard here that actually make this illegal.

Based on [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg#nontype-2)

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a converted constant expression […]

A converted constant expression is a constant expression that is implicitly converted to a particular type [[expr.const]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#7) (here, the type of the template parameter). So your question boils down to the question of whether a variable inside a consteval function is a constant expression. Based on [[expr.const]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#8)

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints: […]

The expression `i` is a glvalue *id-expression* that is a core constant expression (because its evaluation does not do any of the things listed in [[expr.const]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4)). However, the entity this core constant expression refers to is not a permitted result of a constant expression [[expr.const]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#8):

> An entity is a *permitted result of a constant expression* if it is an object with static storage duration that either is not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or if it is a non-immediate function.

The object in question is neither of static storage duration nor is it a temporary object…