# when to use template non-type classes or plain arguments in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, constant-expression

I am very unclear when to use **non-type template arguments** (C++20) or **normal arguments** in constexpr functions. It's unclear to me, what the restrictions are and when to switch from pure parameters to `non-type template parameters` (see [Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6SBu2b6y2luTMPDQ)).
Here an example which illustrates the clunkiness with **normal arguments**:

```cpp
template<typename Tuple, typename Pred>
constexpr auto getLambda(Tuple&& tuple, Pred&& pred)
{
   return [=](auto I, auto J) {
        return pred(std::get<I>(tuple), std::get<J>(tuple));
   };
}

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    constexpr A(T t) : val(t){};
    T val;
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr auto t = std::make_tuple(A{10.0}, A{1});
    constexpr auto p   = [](auto&& a, auto&& b) { return a.val < b.val; };
    constexpr auto s   = getLambda(t, p);
    //constexpr auto b = s(1,0); // that does unfortunately not compile -> go back write differently... :-|||
}
```

Mostly I first try to use normal arguments like above, and after cumbersome fiddling with compile errors about `non-constant` expressions, try an approach with `template<auto t>` (non-type template paramters. Mostly having then two implementations one for each use-case (this seems stupid to me...)

Its sounds to me that modern generic programming with C++20 tends towards compile-time computations using `constexpr` together with some type-meta-programming.
Could anyone shed some light into this rather new "dark-corner" of C++. I probably misunderstand 
when something is not a `constant-expression` and when it is...

Comment: A function parameter is never `constexpr`, only possibly the value returned from the function. A `constexpr` function must be callable both at compile-time and run-time. Hence `I` and `J` are not usable in `std::get`.

Comment: But you might do `constexpr auto b = s(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>{}, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{});` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a7ecef7647ede15)

Comment: @super Why can I then call `getLambda(t,p)`, doesnt evaluating a `constexpr` directly need the argument also a `constant expression` which `t` and `p` are, so `tuple,pred` are constant-expressions ?. Is `constexpr auto s` only a guide that `auto s` might be computed at compile-time, but here it isnt... ?

Comment: @Gabriel `t` and `p` are `constexpr` and guaranteed so. But once you enter the function body of `getLambda`, then `tuple` and `pred` are **not** constant expressions, even if the parameter passed were. Same thing applies to `1/0` and `I/J`.

Comment: Maybe [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0992r0.pdf) will help clarify things more for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will consteval functions allow template parameters dependent on function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130792/will-consteval-functions-allow-template-parameters-dependent-on-function-argumen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version: Use non-type template parameter to set non-type template arguments (more general everywhere, where you need a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)) and normal arguments for everything else.

The thing about `constexpr` functions you always have to keep in mind is that they can also be called at runtime. So every normal argument is not necessarily a constant expression. Hence you cannot use it to provide a non-type template argument (as the `I` in `std::get<I>`).

Of course one could argue that when called to calculate a `constexpr` variable the passed arguments are always constant expressions and could be used as such also inside the function. But it would be unexpected if a `constexpr` function works at compile time but not anymore at runtime.

One could expect that with the new [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) keyword in C++20, one could use normal arguments to `consteval` functions in constant expressions, since we know that these arguments have to be constant expressions. But this does not seem to be the case: https://godbolt.org/z/guz7FQ Why this is the case I do not know. But in general I like the seperation between normal variables and non-type template arguments.

Comment: Some more details on `consteval` and why it's parameters are not usable in constant expressions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226797/will-consteval-allow-using-static-assert-on-function-arguments).