# Parameters of an immediate function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Why are parameters of immediate (`consteval`) functions are not considered constant expressions?

```
consteval void func(int x)
{
   int arr[x]; // not valid, x is not a constant expr
   ...
}
```

What functionality would have been lost if `x` was considered a constant expression? Of course every calls to `func` would have to pass a constant expression as an argument, but this is almost certainly the case anyway, since `func` is immediate.

If there are some *useful* cases where an argument to an immediate function can be a non-constant expression, could we require constexpr-ness of a parameter explicitly, as a hypothetical language extension? Would such extension break any existing code or introduce other problems? (It doesn't have to be limited to immediate functions).

```
consteval void func(constexpr int x)
{
   int arr[x]; // valid, x is a constant expression
   ...
}

func(3); // ok
func(time(nullptr)); // not ok, argument is not a constant expression
```

Are there any committee papers that explore this design?

I know everything can be done with templates:

```
template <int x>
consteval void func()
{
   int arr[x]; // valid, x is a constant expression
   ...
}
```

however templates are syntax-heavy and not very friendly. I would prefer to write `myTuple[3]` rather than `std::get<3>(myTuple)`. It would be possible if arguments to `tuple::operator[]` were constexpr. Since today they are not, such `operator[]` cannot be defined.

Comment: `template <int X> consteval void func() { int arr[X]; }` and `func<3>();` is what you would normally do.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I know I can use a template instead but templates are syntax-heavy. I would much prefer to be able to write `x[3]` instead of `std::get<3>(x)`;

Comment: That makes more sense, perhaps you should mention consteval operator overloading as a motivating factor in your question?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Well, given that *"consteval specifies that a function is an immediate function, that is, **every call to the function must produce a compile-time constant.**"*, the very first question, here, "Why are parameters of immediate (consteval) functions are not considered constant expressions?" sounds motivating enough, to me (how could they not be constant expressions?).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130792/will-consteval-functions-allow-template-parameters-dependent-on-function-argumen

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica close as dup?

Comment: @dyp - Possibly, yes. It's just that with such dark magic question I prefer not to cast a binding vote.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.here's a way you could have a user-defined numeric literal infer the index as a compile-time constant in `my_tuple::operator[]`: https://godbolt.org/z/jhnfdK

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this is interesting and fun but why reimplement the compiler in user code? :)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I agree user-defined literals could have some nicer language support. Maybe a standard library numeric literal suffix which creates a `std::integral_constant` of appropriate width, and then a standard template `operator[]` syntactic sugar accepting an instance of `std::integral_constant` as a function parameter might be a straightforward proposal to implement everywhere that `std::get` is currently used.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That would be useful, but I'd still find the `constexpr` parameter qualification, as proposed by the OP, or even  `constinit` far more practical.

Comment: @Bob_ the duplicate seems to have a sufficient explanation as to why that might probably never be syntactically possible. tl;dr, non-template parameter values should not be able to influence the type of a function. As I've shown though, a literal suffix can be used to capture compile-time constants in trivially inferable type information of the function.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. as it turns out, `boost::hana::tuple` already does exactly what I described above: [`operator[]`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1tuple.html#acef38216a6c6da0296a5f7b5241e951b) and [`operator""_c`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1integral__constant.html#a1c078fd00db48686ca9e0aa17f47344e)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, the duplicate does this in the C++17 context, C++20 brings in abbreviated templates. So a function parameter designated with `constexpr` could trigger an abbreviated template, just like `auto` parameters do.

Comment: I guess you should track the evolution of [P1045R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html), mentioned in Barry's answer.