# Why can't I pass const array references to nested consteval functions?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, consteval

So I've got this code (compiling with clang x86-64 14.0.0):

```
#include <cstdlib>

template <int size>
struct container {
    char data[size];
};

template <size_t n>
consteval size_t func2(const char (&string)[n]) {
    return 1;
}

template <size_t n>
consteval auto func1(const char (&string)[n]) {
    container<func2(string)> result { };
    return result;
}

int main() {
    static constexpr auto var = func1("hi");
}
```

The issue comes into play at the `func2(string)` function call. Replacing `string` with any string literal yields a successful compilation, whereas leaving `string` as-is causes a compiler error:

```
non-type template argument is not a constant expression
```

I fail to see why this non-type template parameter is not a constant expression, does someone have an explanation?

Comment: function parameters are never constant expressions.

Comment: @NathanOliver: While that's true, `consteval` functions have certain interactions with the parameters of `consteval` functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver That seems intensely unreasonable in the context of consteval functions. Are there any plans to remove this restriction?

Comment: @NikTedig Not that I am aware of.  Here is some good reading about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130792/will-consteval-functions-allow-template-parameters-dependent-on-function-argumen

Comment: @NathanOliver Thx, the link answered my question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you have a reference for that?  Everything I recall seeing says the function parameters behave the same way they do in constexpr functions.

Comment: @NikTedig No problem.  Do you want me to close this as a duplicate of that post?

Comment: @NathanOliver Seems like a good idea, go ahead. I'm assuming I can't do it myself, since I don't see a button for that.

Comment: @NathanOliver The special behavior is that a call to a `consteval` function inside another `consteval` function doesn't require the nested `consteval` function call to be a constant expression by itself as well. But I don't think there is anything special if the call is part of an expression that is required to be a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

That the function is `consteval` is not relevant. The expression in the template argument must by itself be a constant expression, which it is not because `string` is a reference-type function parameter (and so its lifetime didn't start with the evaluation of *this* constant expression) and can't be named to in a constant expression.

If it wasn't required that the expression is by itself a constant expression regardless of whether it is located in a `consteval` function or called as part of a constant expression, then you would be able to change the type of an expression as a function of the value passed as function argument. That is not compatible with the type system. (What would e.g. the result of `decltype`/`std::declval` on a call to such a function be?)

However, your functions don't actually try to retrieve the value or address of the object that `string` references at all. So it seems like that shouldn't be an issue and it doesn't have to be.

Up to C++20 there is simply a somewhat unnecessary restriction on constant expressions which disallow naming a reference which is not *usable in constant expressions*, even if no value or address of the referenced object is accessed. With a non-reference parameter on `func1` it would work (but then built-in arrays don't support that).

The restriction will be lifted in C++23 through [P2280](https://wg21.link/p2280), apparently also as a defect report against previous C++ revisions according to the poll results mentioned in the document. The paper mentions basically the same example of obtaining the size of an array. Again, `consteval` is not relevant to this though.