# Initilise std::array member in constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm looking for a way to initialize a `std::array` member.

The constructor defines the size of the array. This size is known at compile-time.

Obviously, I can pass the size of the array via a template parameter.

```
#include <array>

template<size_t x, size_t y>
class MyClass
{
public:
  void memberFunction1();
  void memberFunction2();
  std::array<uint8_t, x*y> m_array;
};
```

However, the problem here is, that I need to carry the template parameters around in all member functions (this makes things much harder to read).

Is there a way to initialize the array in a `constexpr`/`consteval` constructor? So something like that (I could not get it to work though):

```
#include <array>

class MyClass
{
public:
  std::array m_arr;

  explicit consteval MyClass(const size_t x, const size_t y):
    m_arr{uint8_t, x*y}
  {    
  }
};
```

I did not choose `std::vector` or something else, because I'd like to avoid dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: You can't avoid having the parameters on the entire class, because they affect the memory layout of the class.

Comment: You either use templates or pay the cost of dynamic allocation.  An array size must be known at compile time and function parameters are not compile time constants.  Double so that as a class member its size must be defined without even knowing about the constructor

Comment: @NathanOliver: They are (in the context of the call) when the function is `consteval`.  But that doesn't matter to OP.  There's no way to transfer template parameters of a function (which definitely are compile-time constants) up to template parameters of data members, either.

Comment: @BenVoigt (Function parameters are never constant expressions. Even for `consteval` functions they aren't forced to be constant expressions at the call site: https://godbolt.org/z/b8sW3hh7q ) See also this question `MyClass(1, 2)` cannot have a different type to `MyClass(2, 3)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56131346 (you want `constexpr` parameters which haven't been added to C++)

Comment: @Artyer: They have to be constant in the context of the first caller, not in the callee (or intermediate functions of the call graph).  And my first comment explained why the parameter values need to be part of the class type, and therefore class template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CTAD, but need some preparations first:

```
template<std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
struct dims{
    constexpr static std::integral_constant<std::size_t, x> width;
    constexpr static std::integral_constant<std::size_t, y> height;
}; //dims
```

Next we can use `dims` the constructor arguments of our class:

```
template<std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
class my_class{
public:
    constexpr static dims<x,y> size;
    constexpr my_class(dims<x,y>)/*ctor definition*/;
private:
    /*rest of my_class*/
};
```

Now C++20 provides us the default CTAD mechanism:

```
my_class my_object{ dims<my_x,my_y>{} };
```

Notice that for CTAD, all template arguments must be deducible from constructor parameters. In this example we just had dimensional arguments. If there are other arguments in the class template list, they must also be somehow reflected in constructor arguments.
In C++17 you'd need a CTAD directive:

```
template<std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
myclass(dims<x,y>) -> my_class<x,y>;
```

Comment: Terminology: [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: Constructor Template Arguments Deduction.

Comment: thx guys for your answer. I'll try to go with CTAD :)