# Creating custom view::format for piping tuples to fmt::format

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, fmt

(Since I am working with c++20 I am relying on `range-v3` for my ranges!)

I am trying to build a range view which pipes tuples (e.g. from a `zip_view`) to fmt::format automatically. The syntax should be intuitive, e.g.:

```cpp
std::vector v1{"a",     "b",    "c",     "d"};
std::vector v2{"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"};

fmt::print(
    "", 
    fmt::join(views::zip(v1, v2) | views::format("{}: {}"), "\n")
);
```

I know this can be achieved with a simple custom `view::transform` which extracts the relevant tuple args and passes them manually to fmt::format but I would like to eliminate this boilerplate. My attempts are:

```cpp
#define FWD(x) std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)
#define FWD_UNPACK(x) std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...

template <auto str>
struct formatter {
    constexpr auto operator()(auto&&... args) const {
        return fmt::format(str, FWD_UNPACK(args));    
    }
};

namespace ranges::views {

consteval auto format(auto&& format_str) {
    constexpr auto to_format = [=](auto&& args_tuple) {
        return std::apply(
            formatter<format_str>{},
            FWD(args_tuple));
    };
    return transform(to_format);
}

}
```

I have made `format` consteval to ensure that `format_str` would be a constant-time variable, since `fmt::format` requires a constexpr format string to be passed as first argument. However, I am getting the error:

```
<source>:25:23: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
   25 |             formatter<format_str>{},
```

(AUTHOR edit: This approach was never going to work <-- consteval functions do not make the parameters constexpr, see e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130792/will-consteval-functions-allow-template-parameters-dependent-on-function-argumen) and the [related proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1045r0.html) for this language feature)

So as a 2nd attempt I conceded an uglier syntax for a working method:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
struct StringLiteral {
    constexpr StringLiteral(const char (&str)[N]) {
        std::copy_n(str, N, value);
    }
    char value[N];
};

template <StringLiteral str>
struct formatter {
    constexpr auto operator()(auto&&... args) const {
        return fmt::format(str.value, FWD_UNPACK(args));
    }
};

template <StringLiteral format_str>
consteval auto format2() {
    constexpr auto to_format = [=](auto&& args_tuple) {
        return std::apply(formatter<format_str>{}, FWD(args_tuple));
    };
    return transform(to_format);
}
```

which would need to be called like

```cpp
fmt::println(
     "{}", fmt::join(views::zip(v1, v2) | views::format2<"{}: {}">(), "\n"));
```

which works and prints

```
a: alpha
b: beta
c: gamma
d: delta
```

but I am not happy with the unintuitive syntax of it.

Everything is captured in this godbolt example https://godbolt.org/z/x9G96Mncs.

Can someone explain how to make `view::format("{}: {}")` work?

Comment: Take a look at the [A Journey into C++ Ranges, Views, Pipelines, and Currying - Rudyard Merriam - CppNorth 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1aRKYs-FqA). He does almost exactly this throughout his presentation with thorough explanations (except, maybe, direct usage of tuples, but all the mechanics is covered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to accomplish if you don't need to check the format string at compile time. Just use `vformat` instead of `format`.

```cpp
constexpr auto format(std::string_view format_str) {
    auto to_format = [=](auto&& args_tuple) {
        return std::apply([&](auto&... args) {
            return fmt::vformat(format_str, fmt::make_format_args(args...)); },
            args_tuple);
    };
    return std::views::transform(to_format);
}
```

But it is much tricker if you do want to add compile-time checking, although it can be done by performing the check in a `consteval` constructor.

```cpp
struct format_impl {
    std::string_view str;
};

template<class Tuple>
struct format_checker;

template<template<class...> class TupleOrPair, class... Args>
struct format_checker<TupleOrPair<Args...>> {
    consteval format_checker(format_impl f) : str(f.str) {}

    fmt::format_string<Args...> str;
};

template<class R>
auto operator|(R&& range, format_checker<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>> f) {
    auto to_format = [=](auto&& args_tuple) {
        return std::apply([&](auto&... args) {
            return fmt::format(f.str, args...); },
            args_tuple);
    };

    return std::forward<R>(range) | std::views::transform(to_format);
}

consteval auto format(std::string_view format_str) {
    return format_impl(format_str);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts! I would ask some clarification on your consteval solution. My understanding is that the pipe `| format("{}...")` leads the function `format` to create a `format_impl` which in turn will lead to `operator|(R&&, format_checker<...>)` being selected as the only option (due to `format_checker` being implicitly convertible from format_impl). Then `format_checker` fails if the format string doesn't pass checks. Why is the cast to void needed? To ensure no runtime costs, i.e. optimize out this line? Also, why does the pipe operator still use `vformat` here?

Comment: @MichaelA Actually the pipe operator doesn't need to use `vformat`. I've edited the answer to use `format` instead of `vformat`.