# Using an 'int' member as template parameter inside a consteval member function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20

I am trying to use an `int` member of a `constexpr` object as a template parameter. The idea is that I create a `constexpr Symbol` and then have that converted into a `SymbolRef<1>` (in the real code that 1 is different for different objects).

```cpp
template<int Id>
struct SymbolRef { };

struct Symbol {
  int const id_;

  consteval Symbol() : id_(1) { }

  template<int Id>
  consteval operator SymbolRef<Id>() const
  {
    return SymbolRef<id_>{};
  }
};
```

However, [trying to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/7xT7q658h) the above code I get the error:

```
error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
   12 |     return SymbolRef<id_>{};
      |                      ^~~
<source>:12:22: note: implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function
```

The phrase "is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function" seems to not apply: this *is* a `consteval` function!?

I understand that this code is ill-formed when `operator SymbolRef<Id>()` would be a `constexpr` member function (in spite of the error message!) because in that case the function must also compile without the `constexpr`, in which case `this->id_` can't be used as a template parameter.

Why is this code illegal when using it with `consteval`?

EDIT:

The following *does* compile with g++ - but only when using `this->id_`.

```cpp
template<int Id>
struct SymbolRef { };

struct Symbol {
  int const id_;

  consteval Symbol() : id_(1) { }

  template<int Id>
  consteval operator SymbolRef<Id>() const
  {
    return SymbolRef<this->id_>{};
  }
};
```

I am guessing it is a compiler bug therefore? It seems that the correct behavior is that it would compile with or without `this->` and clang++ is just wrong.

Comment: paramer/member are not constexpr, even in `consteval` fonction/class.

Comment: It only compiles on gcc if you don't try to use the operator: https://godbolt.org/z/c5xsaEc9P (Checking errors in templates is best-effort, GCC doesn't *have* to diagnose it, but clang is "smarter" here to reject it)

Comment: Also this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56130792 (`this` is just a function parameter)

Answer (score 2):

`consteval`/`constexpr` is not relevant here.

A non-type template argument, regardless of where it appears, must *itself* be a constant expression.

And the requirement that the compiler error is stating is a bit incomplete. [[expr.const]/5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.1) says:

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - `this`, except in a constexpr function that is being evaluated as part of E;
> - [...]

`id_` in the template argument is implicitly interpreted as `this->id_` because `id_` names a member of the class. This `this` does appear inside a constexpr function, but not a constexpr function that has been invoked during the constant expression evaluation under consideration.

To see why this can't work, consider that the compiler has to determine the type of every expression already when the template is instantiated, before there is any way to know what what value of `id_` the function might be called. Should the type be different for every call to the same function specialization? That's not possible in a statically-typed language.

---

Note that there will generally only be an error if you actually try to instantiate a specialization of the member function.

However, the compiler is free to decide to fail early if a non-dependent construct would always cause any instantiation to fail. (Technically such a program is IFNDR: *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.)

Comment: This is still a bit over my head... it seems to me that it would be possible to instantiate the member function at the moment it is called, because it is called on a constexpr Symbol, with known id_ value at the time of compilation. You CAN do: `constexpr Symbol x; Foo<x.id_> foo;` assuming Foo<int> exists (or `static_assert(x.id_ == 1, "!!");`).

Comment: @CarloWood Yes, but in `constexpr Symbol x; Foo<x.id_> foo;` the type of `foo` is always the same and can be determined immediately when it is being parsed. `constexpr` doesn't affect anything about how syntax in functions works: Every expression in a `constexpr` or `consteval` function has a specific type that can be identified from the function's definition wherever it is placed (or instantiated). A function can't have an expression which sometime has one type and sometimes another. It is just completely contrary to how the language works.

Comment: @CarloWood You _can_ have a function template with each specialization of it having a different type for the same expression, but each specialization of such a template is itself a unique function. You can achieve this by making `id_` a template parameter of the function instead and passing it in wherever the function is called, similar to what you showed in your previous comment.

Comment: @CarloWood Or stated in a different way: In C++ types are always resolved first, while parsing the definition or during template instantiation from a definition. Constant expression evaluation always happens afterwards in a separate step and doesn't differ from runtime evaluation in any way other than that the result may under certain circumstances be used in some places that require a constant expression and that there are constructs like `if consteval` to intentionally cause divergence during the evaluation.

Comment: Yes, but `this->id_` *does* always have the same value in the template function `template<int Id> consteval operator SymbolRef<Id>() const`. That is the whole idea, that I generate a new function for every (different) value of `id_`. You said "A function can't have an expression which sometime has one type and sometimes another." but that isn't the case here :/

Comment: @CarloWood Your function is templated on `Id` only. For every value of `Id` there is exactly one specialization of the template that is an individual function. But for every value of `Id`, the value of `this->id_` can still be completely arbitrary, i.e. none of these specializations is fixed on a specific value in the template argument and thus not fixed on a specific type for the expresison `SymbolRef<this->id_>{}`.

Comment: @CarloWood That said, why is it `return SymbolRef<id_>{};` instead of `return SymbolRef<Id>{};`? What is the intention here? Why is the operator templated at all? Shouldn't it be the _class type_ that is templated and then doesn't need any state?

Comment: "To see why this can't work, consider that the compiler has to determine the type of every expression already when the template is instantiated, before there is any way to know what what value of id_ the function might be called" no, C++ could do this.  Any given call of that operator is in a consteval context (at compile time) with a known id value (calculated at compile time).  It is free to invent the needed type at compile time.  C++ compile time programming is, however, limited to what compiler writers *find easy* as a matter of practicality.

Comment: @user17732522 This came from code where `Id` is a compiler-time counter (incremented every function instantiation) and I was attempting to store that Id as a constexpr: as a const member of a non-template class instantiated as a constexpr. Aka `static constexpr Symbol x("x");` so that from now on there is a `Symbol const&` (or the address of x) that points to a variable part and the `Id`. Adding a `consteval int id() const { return id_; }` should then return the id as constexpr, even though the object itself is not a template. But apparently the compiler can't keep track of this constexpr-ness

Comment: PS I reported this as a compiler-bug; and so far it seems that the compiler devs (well, Andrew - who I hold in the highest possible regard) think that it might indeed be valid code (hence, a bug in the compiler). See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114311

Comment: @CarloWood The potential duplicate linked there is very different from your example in the important bits. I think he just didn't read it carefully enough. In the linked bug there is no dependence on state of `this`. `this` is not used in any expression (implicitly or explicitly) and no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an object whose lifetime began outside the constant expression evaluation. In your example such a conversion does happen and `this` is being used in the constant expression evaluation.